# Trouble installing R-2.15.2 on Fedora 14

Tags: r, makefile, fedora

I need to install **R-2.15.2**, the latest version. 
I tried using

```
blah> sudo yum install R
```

to install R, but for whatever reason (maybe because it's an old version of Fedora?) my system thinks R version **13** is the most recent. So, I downloaded the .tar.gz file from R's site and used the following:

```
blah> tar -xvf R-2.15.2.tar.gz
```

This successfully unzipped the file. I then ran:

```
blah> ./configure

blah/R-2.15.2> ls

ChangeLog     COPYING  Makeconf.in  ONEWS   src       VERSION-NICK
config.log    doc      Makefile.fw  OONEWS  SVN-REVISION
config.site   etc      Makefile.in  po      tests
configure     INSTALL  NEWS     README  tools
configure.ac  m4       NEWS.pdf     share   VERSION
```

As you can see, makefiles are present. However, when I run "make" within the R folder, I get the following error:

```
blah/R-2.15.2> make

make: No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Is there any way I can fix this issue? I'm guessing people will recommend updating Fedora, but is there another way?

Comment: Actually, there is no makefile. You should have 'Makefile' there.

Comment: I see 'Makefile.fw' and 'Makefile.in'. Not right?

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the command **./configure** terminate successfully. If **./configure** return without error, there should be a file named with **Makefile**.

Answer (score 0):

Comment seems to be very long, so posted this answer.

You should see just **Makefile** - no Makefile.in, Makefile.fw or Makefile.whatdoyouwant - just **Makefile**. This file appears after **./configure** was successful. If you don't see just **Makefile** - then **./configure** was not successful. So read its output and try to understand what it needs to do its work right way.

Answer (score 0):

Run ./configure in the R-2.15.2 directory not in the blah directory.  You should get a whole stream of output from ./configure if it runs.  Once that is done, make should work.